# Sistema de búsqueda en ajax y php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

El Error que tengo no me muestra el resultado en el debido 
'resultado'
tengo el siguiente código

test2.php

```
 $search = '';

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE articulo LIKE '%" .$search. "%' OR nombre  LIKE '%" .$search. "%' ORDER BY visit LIMIT 5";
$resultado = $con->query($consulta);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
?>

<?php if ($total>0 && $search!='') { ?>
        <h1>Resultado</h1>

              <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>
              <?php echo $fila['articulo']; ?>
        <?php  while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){; ?>    

<?php } } ?>
```

y en ajax tengo lo siguiente

```
 $(function(){
    $('#search_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var envio = $('#search').val();

        $('#resultado').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test2.php',
            data: ('search='+envio),
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp!="") {
                    $('#resultado').html(resp);
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="search_form" id="search_form">
                  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
                </form>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En *Test2.php* estás leyendo el parámetro "search" por `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}
```

En cambio estás enviando la información por `$_POST`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test2.php',
    data: ('search='+envio),
    success: function(resp){
        if(resp!="") {
            $('#resultado').html(resp);
        }
    }
})
```

Por lo tanto la variable de búsqueda siempre está vacía.

Comment: Si bien esto responde la pregunta, deberías aclararle al usuario que esta forma de hacerlo permite inyección de SQL y es un riesgo a la seguridad. Para redondear la respuesta, poner un ejemplo de como sanear la entrada. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo test2.php veo un punto y coma que no debería de ir ahí.

```
<?php  while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){; ?>
```

Comment: Aun sigue igual